# update sqlite3 table from another one

Tags: sqlite, join

Question is relevant only to SQLite3. How to update a table row from another table?
My example:

Table "cashpoints" has columns "id", "bank_id" 
Table "banks_cashpoints" has columns "cp_id", "b_id" 
Tables should be joined by condition

```
cashpoints.id = banks_cashpoints.cp_id
```

So I need: banks_cashpoints.b_id -> cashpoints.bank_id

Each of my attempts failed. For example this (ERROR: near "from": syntax error):

```
UPDATE cashpoints
SET bank_id = b_id
    FROM banks_cashpoints bc
WHERE cp_id = id
```

As I read [here](http://sqlite.org/lang%5Fupdate.html), it's not possible to use FROM statement is update query. But I have no idea how to do this without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it works, but it's worth trying:

```
UPDATE
  cashpoints
SET
  bank_id = b_id
WHERE
  b_id IN (
    SELECT
      b_id
    FROM
      banks_cashpoints
    WHERE
      cp_id = id
  );
```

Comment: No, it doesn't :( "no such column: b_id"

Comment: Found it, there's no need to separate using nested query. Try this: `UPDATE
  cashpoints
SET
  bank_id = (
    SELECT
      b_id
    FROM
      banks_cashpoints
    WHERE
      cp_id = id
  );`